# Node/Express/MongoDB: POST embedded object returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

I have a simple `POST` route:

```
  // -------------- CREATE Event --------------
  app.post('/events', (req, res) => {

    var event = 
    { 
      title : req.body.title,
      description : req.body.description,
      address : {
        street: req.body.address.street,
        city : req.body.address.city,
        state : req.body.address.state 
      }
    }

    db.collection('events').insert( event, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' }) 
      }
      else { 
        // RETURNS: "{street : \"streetname\", city :  \"cityname\", state : \"statename\"}"
        console.log(JSON.stringify( req.body.address ))

        // RETURNS: {"title":"First Event","description":"this is my first event title","address":{},"_id":"591f512b15d612fc110dd31f"}
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.ops[0]))

        res.send(result.ops[0])
      }
    })

    // RETURNS: {street : "streetname", city :  "cityname", state : "statename"}
    console.log(req.body.address) 

  })
```

When I submit a POST request via Postman...
[image]

...The embedded object's value results in null when created, but the `req.body.address` outside of the `.insert()` method shows that the ` is intact.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591f49519eb9e5facb6352fe"),
    "title" : "First Event",
    "description" : "this is my first event title",
    "address" : {
        "street" : null,
        "city" : null,
        "state" : null
    }
}
```

---

**tl;dr** How am I able to send an embedded object to MongoDB without the embedded object's values turning to null?

**NOTES:**

- Yes I am including `app.use(bodyParser.json())` and `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`
- Using latest versions of body-parser, express and mongodb
- Using `x-www-form-urlencoded` on data-type for Postman

Comment: Could you put more details about your `event` Schema?

Comment: @LeandroRodrigues not using `mongoose`, but the schema is the request sent as you can see from the image of my Postman request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error wasn't in the code, but rather in Postman. To send complex objects, such as a nested JSON object, you have to change a couple details on your Postman request:

1. **Change your Headers**

   - `Content-Type` : `application/json`
   - `Accept` : `application/json`
2. **Change the data-type within Body**

   - switch to the `raw` radio-button
   - Change the type to: `JSON(application/json)`

---

**tl;dr** remember to change your Postman configs for JSON when sending POST requests